# Deleting Repetitive Lines

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

This should be pretty simple. I need to write a shell script to do the following (sorry, I'm a beginner):

Suppose I have a file:

```
act="1" bar="moreCrap" interesting="car" foo="I"
act="1" bar="that" interesting="car" foo="just"
act="1" bar="matters" interesting="truck" foo="need"
act="1" bar="to" interesting="sedan" foo="a"
act="1" bar="no" interesting="sedan" foo="regex "
act="1" bar="one" interesting="truck" foo="matcher"
act="1" bar="including" interesting="tricycle" foo="that"
act="1" bar="me" interesting="truck" foo="will"
act="1" bar="or" interesting="sedan" foo="delete"
act="1" bar="even" interesting="sedan" foo="repetitions"
act="1" bar="you" interesting="sedan" foo="of"
act="1" bar="lol" interesting="sedan" foo="stuff"
act="1" bar="me" interesting="truck" foo="ha"
act="2" bar="no" interesting="sedan" foo="regex "
act="2" bar="one" interesting="truck" foo="matcher"
act="2" bar="including" interesting="tricycle" foo="that"
act="2" bar="me" interesting="truck" foo="will"
act="2" bar="or" interesting="sedan" foo="delete"
act="2" bar="even" interesting="sedan" foo="repetitions"
act="2" bar="you" interesting="sedan" foo="of"
act="2" bar="lol" interesting="sedan" foo="stuff"
act="2" bar="me" interesting="truck" foo="ha"
act="2" bar="me" interesting="truck" foo="ha"
```

I need to extract all the strings followed by interesting=,
and if there are four continuous repetitions of "sedan", the last two repetitions should be deleted along with the rest of the lines that corresponds to that act. In this case, the output should look like this:

```
act="1" bar="moreCrap" interesting="car" foo="I"
act="1" bar="that" interesting="car" foo="just"
act="1" bar="matters" interesting="truck" foo="need"
act="1" bar="to" interesting="sedan" foo="a"
act="1" bar="no" interesting="sedan" foo="regex "
act="1" bar="one" interesting="truck" foo="matcher"
act="1" bar="including" interesting="tricycle" foo="that"
act="1" bar="me" interesting="truck" foo="will"
act="1" bar="or" interesting="tricycle" foo="delete"
act="1" bar="even" interesting="tricycle" foo="repetitions"
act="2" bar="no" interesting="sedan" foo="regex "
act="2" bar="one" interesting="truck" foo="matcher"
act="2" bar="including" interesting="tricycle" foo="that"
act="2" bar="me" interesting="truck" foo="will"
act="2" bar="or" interesting="sedan" foo="delete"
act="2" bar="even" interesting="sedan" foo="repetitions"
```

Thanks all.

Comment: This is indeed one problem, I'm just showing an intermediate step.

Answer (score 1):

This awk one-liner does it:

```
awk -F'interesting="' '{t=$2;sub(/".*/,"",t)}a[t]++<3' file
```

test with your input:

```
kent$  awk -F'interesting="' '{t=$2;sub(/".*/,"",t)}a[t]++<3' f
foo="crap" bar="moreCrap" interesting="car" wow="I"
foo="that" bar="that" interesting="car" wow="just"
foo="really" bar="matters" interesting="truck" wow="need"
foo="does" bar="to" interesting="sedan" wow="a"
foo="not" bar="no" interesting="sedan" wow="regex "
foo="matter" bar="one" interesting="truck" wow="matcher"
foo="to" bar="including" interesting="tricycle" wow="that"
foo="me" bar="me" interesting="truck" wow="will"
foo="at" bar="or" interesting="tricycle" wow="delete"
foo="all" bar="even" interesting="tricycle" wow="repetitions"
```

Comment: Thanks Kent! Do you think you could edit your response and explain a little bit? All this stuff is new to me and I am trying to familiarize myself!

Comment: @ZtoYi wait, I realized that the answer perhaps doesn't do exactly what you want..... this does only keep the first 3 occurrences of interesting field value......... It is also okay for your requirement?

Comment: My scenario is actually a little more complicated (sorry just realized). I will edit my question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe looks a little discomfort, but this meet your need well

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
BEGIN { rep = 0; cnt = 0; }
{
    if (skipact != $1) {
        if ( act == $1 && interest == $3 ) {
            rep++;
        } else {
            rep = 1;
            act = $1;
            interest = $3;
        }

        if (rep == 3) {
            tmp = $0;
            getline;

            if (act != $1 || interest != $3) {
                arr[cnt++] = tmp;
            } else {
                skipact = $1;
            }
        } else {
            arr[cnt++] = $0;
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (i = 0 ; i < cnt ; ++i) {
        print arr[i];
    }
}
'
```

Comment: You are putting all lines in a new array and printing it? There is no reason to save all the lines. For big files, this is not a good idea. It would be simpler to delete lines.

Comment: @ZtoYi Oh yeah, but I just can't find other solution now